# How can I delete repetitive values in vector with order?

Tags: c++, string, file, vector, stl

I have a txt file with 3 columns: `"dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS number(000.000)"`. There are about 368 entries.

I want to choose `strings`, where the value form the 3rd column is unique (meets for the first time). Order is important.

In my code I read file in `vector` (`dtp`) and then fill each `column` in `vector` (`data`, `time`, `pressure`). Then I delete values from 3rd column and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ6w6.png).

My question is how can I add the 1st and the 2nd columns with the right indices and get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiy6P.png)?

Data examples (firs 15 values):

```
26.07.2017  15:47:38    82.431 
26.07.2017  16:47:46    83.431
26.07.2017  17:47:54    85.431
26.07.2017  18:48:02    84.431
26.07.2017  19:48:09    83.431
26.07.2017  20:48:17    83.431
26.07.2017  21:48:24    84.431
26.07.2017  22:48:32    83.431
26.07.2017  23:48:40    83.431
27.07.2017  00:48:48    84.431
27.07.2017  01:48:55    84.431
27.07.2017  02:49:03    84.431
27.07.2017  03:49:10    84.431
27.07.2017  04:49:19    84.431
27.07.2017  05:49:27    86.431
```

Code:

```
include <iostream> 
include <fstream> 
include <string> 
include <algorithm> 
include <iterator> 
include <sstream> 
include <vector> 
include <cstring> 
include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const clock_t start = clock(); 
    system("mode con cols=50 lines=1000"); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); 

    vector<string> dtp; 
    vector<string> data;
    vector<string> time;
    vector<double> pressure;
    double num(0.0); 
    string line, tmp1, tmp2; 
    int len = 368;
    int f, i, j, k;

    ifstream file("data.txt"); 

    while (!getline(file, line).eof()) 
        dtp.push_back(line); 

    for (string &it : dtp) 
    { 
        {
            istringstream isstr(it);
            isstr >> tmp1;
            data.push_back(tmp1);
        }

        {
            istringstream isstr(it);
            isstr >> tmp1 >> tmp2;
            time.push_back(tmp2);
        }

        {
            istringstream isstr(it);
            isstr >> tmp1 >> tmp2 >> num;
            pressure.push_back(num);
        }

    }

    f = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) 
        {
            if (pressure[i] == pressure[j]) 
            {
                for (k = j; k < (len - 1); k++)
                    pressure[k] = pressure[k + 1];

                len--;
                j--;
                f = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (f == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
            cout << pressure[i] << endl;
    }

    const double vremya = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    cout << "Time is: " << vremya << " seconds" << endl; 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the data examples in the question; not links, not screenshots.

Comment: Consider keeping your 3 values together in a struct. As you read each value add the 3rd column to a set or an unordered_set if it isn't already there, and if it is toss that data.

Comment: @Beta thank your for your comment

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks a lot for help, I will try to do it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would do better to think of this as a table with two columns:

```
Timestamp Pressure
```

And work with that instead.  And to work with a time stamp it helps to use a [date/time library which can parse, format and order time stamps](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

Here is what it could look like.  Details explanation below the code:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::istringstream file
{
    "26.07.2017  15:47:38    82.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  16:47:46    83.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  17:47:54    85.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  18:48:02    84.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  19:48:09    83.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  20:48:17    83.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  21:48:24    84.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  22:48:32    83.431\n"
    "26.07.2017  23:48:40    83.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  00:48:48    84.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  01:48:55    84.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  02:49:03    84.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  03:49:10    84.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  04:49:19    84.431\n"
    "27.07.2017  05:49:27    86.431\n"
};

int
main()
{
    using record = std::pair<date::sys_seconds, double>;
    std::vector<record> records;
    while (file)
    {
        record r;
        file >> date::parse(" %d.%m.%Y %T", r.first) >> r.second;
        if (file.fail())
            break;
        records.push_back(std::move(r));
    }
    std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
                                                  {return x.first < y.first;});
    std::stable_sort(records.begin(), records.end(),
                     [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
                         {return x.second < y.second;});
    records.erase(std::unique(records.begin(), records.end(),
                              [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
                                  {return x.second == y.second;}),
                  records.end());
    std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), [](const auto& x, const auto& y)
                                                    {return x.first < y.first;});
    for (const auto& r : records)
        std::cout << date::format("%d.%m.%Y %T ", r.first) << r.second << '\n';
}
```

For ease of presentation I've placed your `data.tx` into a `istringstream`.  Don't let that detail trip you up.  `main` will work equally fine with a `istringstream` or a `ifstream`.

I'm reusing `std::pair` as my `record`, but you could write your own `record` struct if you prefer.  In any event, you want to collect a `vector<record>` from your database.  This is what the `while` loop does.  This loop uses [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) to parse the timestamp, but there are several other solutions you could use as well.

Once you have `records` filled from your database, there are three `std::algorithms` that will do this job for you (in 4 steps):

1. sort `records` by timestamp.
2. stable sort `records` by pressure.  For equal pressures this preserves the sorted order of the timestamps.
3. unique the list for equal pressures.  This algorithm moves duplicate pressures to the back of the list and returns an iterator to the "new end" of the list.  You then need to erase everything from `[new_end, old_end)`.
4. sort by timestamp one last time if you wish to view the list in chronological order.

And you're done!  Just print it out.  This will output:

```
26.07.2017 15:47:38 82.431
26.07.2017 16:47:46 83.431
26.07.2017 17:47:54 85.431
26.07.2017 18:48:02 84.431
27.07.2017 05:49:27 86.431
```

which matches the prefix of your desired output.

Comment: thank your, this is really beautiful. am I right that auto& works only in C++14 standart?

Comment: That's correct.  For C++11 you'll need to sub in `record` for `auto` in the lambda parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your insert order correspond to date/time order. if that is the case, you may do something like:

```
struct Record
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point time_point;
    double pressure;
};

std::vector<Record> records = /**/;

const auto lessPressure = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& lhs){
    return lhs.pressure < rhs.pressure;
};
std::stable_sort(records.begin(), records.end(), lessPressure);
const auto equalPressure = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& lhs){
    return lhs.pressure == rhs.pressure;
};
records.erase(std::unique(records.begin(), records.end(), equalPressure), records.end());
const auto lessTimePoint = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& lhs){
    return lhs.time_point< rhs.time_point;
};
std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), lessTimePoint );
```

Else, from your code, you have to report changes done to `pressure` vector to other data:

so change:

```
for (k = j; k < (len - 1); k++)
    pressure[k] = pressure[k + 1];
```

to

```
for (k = j; k < (len - 1); k++) {
    pressure[k] = pressure[k + 1];
    data[k] = data[k + 1];
    time[k] = time[k + 1];
}
```

or even

```
pressure.erase(pressure.begin() + j);
data.erase(data.begin() + j);
time.erase(time.begin() + j);
```

Comment: thank you for help, will understand your code to reach new knowledge